# placing a menu block inside a views template

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I need to place a menu block (the main-menu) inside a views template file - the template for the rows design.

I tried

$block = module_invoke('system','main_menu');
print render($block['content']);

and

$block = module_invoke('menu','main_menu');
print render($block['content']);

but nothing works.

Can anyone please give me a little help?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731420/how-to-insert-a-block-into-a-node-or-template-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

I used the code which was rendering the `main-menu` from `page.tpl.php` file in the theme that I am using in my current project [Nexus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nexus).

```
<div id="main-menu">
<?php
 if (module_exists('i18n_menu')) {
   $main_menu_tree = i18n_menu_translated_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
 }
 else {
   $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
}
 print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
 ?>
</div>
```

So i used the following extraction:

```
<?php
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
?>
```

in a views template file for row design. The main menu appeared with content.

Note: The menu which will be rendered might not be themed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by placing the region with the block into the view template:

```
<?php print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('mainmenu')); ?>
```

That works.